# what is the vb6 kill statement equivalent in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb6

What is the vb6 kill function equivalent in c#?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1w10ch(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MSDN [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2):

```
File.Delete(<filename>);
```

Comment: There is a minor difference: the VB6 `Kill` raises an error if the file does not exist, but the C#/.Net `File.Delete` does not.

Comment: True, so a simple call to File.Exists(<filename>) allows you to check that before hand. Mind you, if you're trying to delete a file it's not usually an issue if the file doesn't exist to begin with.